# Cant download GeoIP data for - Nginx >> GeoIP - 404 Error - Resolving geolite.maxmind.com (geolite.maxmind.com)

Tags: nginx, geoip

Following along the Nginx CookBook - cant seem to download GeoIP data , error in terminal as below -

```
/etc/nginx/geoip$ wget "http://geolite.maxmind.com/\
> download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz"
--2019-10-22 15:55:46--  http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz
Resolving geolite.maxmind.com (geolite.maxmind.com)... 104.17.200.89, 104.17.201.89, 2606:4700::6811:c959, ...
Connecting to geolite.maxmind.com (geolite.maxmind.com)|104.17.200.89|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2019-10-22 15:55:48 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Kindly suggest an alternative - the GeoIP folks mention somewhere here - https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/ , to post questions on SO .

Answer (score 4):

Those databases have been discontinued. However, you can still find them on Web Archive.

http://web.archive.org/web/20181229152721/http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz

Comment: Useful! I reinstalled the PHP geoip extension with PECL on 2020/03 and the `GeoIP.dat` file was here but empty. So PHP was raising the error "Message: geoip_country_name_by_name(): Required database not available at /usr/local/var/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat." I replaced this empty file with this one and it worked (I don't care if it isn't up to date, it was to avoid the error locally).

Answer (score 3):

You have to register for an MaxMind account now. See this Blogpost from MaxMind for more Information: https://blog.maxmind.com/2019/12/18/significant-changes-to-accessing-and-using-geolite2-databases/